# In XML Excel - when does ss:ArrayRange="RC" come into play?

Tags: xml, excel

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s27"
 ss:ArrayRange="RC"
 ss:Formula="=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(RC[1]:RC[9]),3)&lt;&gt;MOD(COLUMN(),3),0,RC
    [1]:RC[9]))">
<Data  ss:Type="Number">3</Data></Cell>
```

Hi, I have a system which creates a Excel XML file. Now we have this formula where we couldn't just press enter on the formula, has to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER in order to "submit" it successfully.

Now when I manually add the formula, and save it, and then open the XML Excel file in Notepad, then I see that  `ss:ArrayRange="RC"`  has been added. I would need to add this into my code, but I don't know when it would be required to use `ss:ArrayRange="RC"` and what it means please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ss:ArrayRange` specifies an array formuala and range

See [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

### Extract from the article

**Attribute:**  ss:ArrayRange

**Description:**    Specifies the range of cells onto which we apply an array formula. When an array formula is specified, only the top-left cell contains an ArrayRange and Formula attribute. Other cells in the range do not contain ArrayRange or Formula. This reference may be any valid reference as long as the ss:ArrayRange attribute appears in the top-left corner of the array. For example, this means if I have an array in cells A1:B2, A1 must have the ArrayRange attribute, but the specified range reference could be B1:A2.

**Example:**

```
<ss:Table>
    <ss:Row ss:Height="3">
        <ss:Cell ss:ArrayRange="R1C1:R2C2" 
                      ss:Formula="={1,2;3,4}">
            <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">1</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">2</ss:Data>
        </ss:Cell>
    </ss:Row>
    ...
</ss:Table>
```